# Table with relation manyToMany

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have entity like that:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;
}
```

I want to create table like that:

```
CREATE TABLE user_to_sub_user (
    user_id int,
    sub_user_id int
);
```

which will be showing me users that are sub-users to other users. How can I map this and connect to User using hibernate?

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of examples online about this kind of mapping. Just search for "Hibernate many to many" and you will find what you are looking for. For example: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many